# What are the drawbacks, if any, of killing everyone in Paradise Falls?

Tags: fallout-3

I went to rescue the two kids from the slavers in Paradise Falls to get access to the vault. I didn't want to enslave anyone, so I snuck in and ended up having to kill almost everyone. There were also two slave girls that were hostile that I ended up having to kill.  I got all the people out of the cages successfully...

Should I have enslaved the other people only to release them with the children?  Did I screw anything up by killing off everyone?

Also, I noticed, after I had killed everyone, in one of the bathrooms a sewer drain that I was too small for me.  Could I have stealthed through the entire place and got the kids out through the sewer?

Comment: [Axl Rose](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rbm6GXllBiw) might not be too pleased...

Comment: lol.. wrong city

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you gain access to Paradise Falls the normal way - through the quest to enslave a few NPCs - then you get the chance to 1) Recruit Clover (one of the slave girls you killed) and 2) Continue enslaving NPCs (with the mesmetron) for caps. You also miss one or two minor sidequests, like giving the trader 10 Chinese Assault Rifles to expand his stock and caps.

But, beyond Clover, you will miss out on nothing major and if you feel like not being an evil bastard and working for slavers then certainly feel free to kill them all.

In most of my playthroughs I tended to sign up normally by enslaving the sniper who is hostile in the mined town north of Germantown then I recruit Clover, then I redeem myself by purging Paradise Falls :)

Comment: haha.. nice. thanks for the answer, I don't feeel too bad about the slaughter then.

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do was talk to the kids in the pen. Would have told you either fix cables near food place or the terminal in Eugene's house. Then tell forks Eugene is looking for him and get him busy so the kids can escape through the small hole you mentioned. No one has to die and kids get out quick without anyone seeing them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get both with good karma you go to Eugene and ask if you can buy the kids the kids will be mad at u until after u get them outside the town but after that ur good they actually yell thank you for our freedom or something like that and they can be found at lamp light caverns

Answer (score 0):

Not only are there not any consequences for going in and killing all the slavers, but you will actually get positive karma for every named slaver in the central compound and buildings you kill.